# Submenu tableView on only one cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've been looking around for some time and couldn't find how you can make an `tableView` with cells, where only **one** `cell` can have a submenu.

For example like the image below. I don't want the *"Main"* and *"About us"* cells to be expandable on click. But I want the *"Categories"* cell to expand as submenus.

[image]

I appreciate any answers, thanks!

Comment: Create a section Table view with three section Main,about us , category , add tap gesture on category  on action event of it add rows in that section ,That's it

Comment: Oh it was that easy. Thank you @Jon Snow i'll try it out!

Comment: Demo  But it is in obj c  http://www.iostute.com/2015/04/expandable-and-collapsable-tableview.html :)

Comment: I created the sections yesterday and added the tap gestures on every header, then I added a `header.tag = section` so I could use a switch to change the views depending on which tag it had. Thank you @JonSnow for the advice!